# Use secure string in SAM template

Tags: aws-sam, aws-ssm

In my template, I can use a configured parameter from systems manager, like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
  DatabasePassword:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Default: '/some/path/db_password'
```

However, I need help to be able to use a [secure string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html).

I tried: `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<SecureString>` and `/some/path/db_password~true`

Perhaps it is not worth the trouble to use a secure string in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a note on the aws docs that mention...

> AWS CloudFormation doesn't support creating a SecureString parameter type.

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html#cfn-ssm-parameter-datatype

You may want to instead want to create your SecureString ssm parameters via the AWS CLI

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --name parameter-name \
    --value "parameter-value" \
    --type SecureString
```

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html

Comment: I saw a request logged for it on GitLab: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/82